# Where can I get information on how to implement AES?

Tags: aes, block-cipher

I want to write AES from scratch without using the built in libraries of java. I know there are hundreds of AES programs (and websites) out there but I can't seem to find a site that gives me the details I think I would/should need to write my own Java program.

I know that AES has S-boxes like DES has. Were would I look for them? Also, I would like more info on the AES "counter mode".

Comment: Just a note: For productive use, you often want to use existing implementations instead of creating your own, since they probably are better shielded against side-channel attacks, and might also be more efficient (e.g. might use AES-specific instructions on modern processors). For learning about the internal workings it is a good idea to implement it yourself, though.

Comment: For reference, a Java implementation of FIPS AES can be found in the Bouncy Castle open source project: http://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html

Comment: My python implementation of AES is supposed to be very easy to read, and it's got a good few comments. For what it's worth, it might help you or someone else implementing aes: http://code.google.com/p/zs-crypto/source/browse/zs/cipher/aes.py. A tip: read this code together with the wikipedia articles on AES. Most of the maths turns out to be really straightforward.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [AES standard](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf) is reasonably clear, and (theoretically) sufficient to implement the AES itself. For block cipher modes of operation (including counter mode), see [NIST Special Publication 800-38A](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38a/sp800-38a.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

One thing I would like to add to Thomas's answer: when implementing a cipher, it's useful to have a test vector with the cipher intermediate states (if you get it right the first time, you don't need it; if you get a detail wrong, it makes finding that detail a lot easier).

The document http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf has all those intermediate states (both for the key expansion and the actual block encrypt operations; the decrypt is just a reversal of the encrypt operations, so they don't need to spell it out explicitly).

Comment: While I do thanks you for the help. Thomas Pornin first link is the same as the one you posted.

Comment: Oops, I missed that his 'The AES standard' was a link...

Answer (score 3):

In the Rijndael proposal [document](http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/rijndael/Rijndael-ammended.pdf#page=19) a clear explanation of the possible implementations is given. It was later completed by D. J. Bernstein (https://cr.yp.to/aes-speed.html) with further optimizations. However as said before, be careful of the possible side channel attacks which may applied to your implementation.